# Tkinter: share single Frame accross multiple tabs (or dynamically reparent)

Tags: python, tkinter

I have `tkinter.Notebook` that contains multiple tabs.
I have `tkinter.Frame` "run box" with set of controls, that I want share across several tabs. Specifically `Test info` and `Test list` should have it.

[image]

Currently I duplicate entire "run box" into each tab that needs it. And it works somewhat fine, but feels excessive and not right, because code behind "run box" controls is almost identical.

Ideally I want this "run box" to be single instance and dynamically shown on active tab. Can anyone advise how to detach"run box" from one tab and re-attach to different tab? I would do that on `Notebook` switch event.

Comment: You might be able to use the `in_=` parameter of `.pack()` and `.grid()` to move this Frame into different containers (it would have to actually be a child of some ancestor of all the containers, perhaps the Notebook or the window itself).  There would likely be some issues with layering, which could be fixed with `.lift()` or `.lower()`.

Comment: Sounds promising. I use `grid` layout. Assume I have `self.notebook`, `self.frmRunBox`, `self.tab1` and `self.tab2`. Could you please put your comment as answer and write simple example how to do what you suggest?

Comment: For your case, suggest to use `Radiobutton` widgets instead of `Notebook` widget for selecting the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A widget can only be in one place at a time. There is no way to share a frame among multiple notebook tabs without removing it from one tab and adding it to another when the active tab changes.

If that's what you want to do, you can create the "runbox" once, and then add a container to each tab to act as a placeholder. You can add a binding to the `<Visibility>` event to add the runbox to the placeholder when it becomes visible.

This might cause some flickering as you switch tabs.

The key to this working is to use the `in_` parameter to `pack` which lets you pack one widget inside another widget. It also uses the `lift` mechanism to make sure that the "runbox" is higher in z-order than the placeholder. The runbox is re-packed whenever its visibility changes, by binding to the `<Visibility>` event.

Here's an example. It creates a single instance of `Runbox` and swaps it between two tabs.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class RunParameters():
    """Parameters to be shared by all tabs"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.magic_num = tk.IntVar(value=0)
        self.iter_count = tk.IntVar(value=1)
        self.duration = tk.IntVar(value=0)
        self.result = "fail"
        self.repeat = tk.BooleanVar(value=True)

class Runbox(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, run_parameters):
        super().__init__(parent)
        radiobuttons = []
        for i in (range(8)):
            rb = tk.Radiobutton(
                self, text=i, variable=run_parameters.magic_num, value=i
            )
            radiobuttons.append(rb)

        itercount_spinbox = tk.Spinbox(
            self, from_=1, to=100,
            textvariable=run_parameters.iter_count
        )
        duration_spinbox = tk.Spinbox(
            self, from_=0, to=100,
            textvariable=run_parameters.duration
        )

        radiobuttons[0].grid(row=0, column=0)
        radiobuttons[1].grid(row=0, column=1)
        radiobuttons[2].grid(row=0, column=2)
        radiobuttons[3].grid(row=0, column=3)
        radiobuttons[4].grid(row=1, column=0)
        radiobuttons[5].grid(row=1, column=1)
        radiobuttons[6].grid(row=1, column=2)
        radiobuttons[7].grid(row=1, column=3)
        itercount_spinbox.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=4)
        duration_spinbox.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=4)

class TestInfo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, runbox):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.runbox = runbox
        self._container = tk.Frame(self)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Something unique to the Test Info tab")
        self._container.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        label.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.bind("<Visibility>", self.on_vis)

    def on_vis(self, event):
        if self.winfo_viewable():
            self.runbox.pack(in_=self._container, fill="both", expand=True)
            self.runbox.lift()

class TestList(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, runbox):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.runbox = runbox
        self._container = tk.Frame(self)
        listbox = tk.Listbox(self)
        listbox.insert("end", "Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3")
        self._container.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        listbox.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.bind("<Visibility>", self.on_vis)

    def on_vis(self, event):
        if self.winfo_viewable():
            self.runbox.pack(in_=self._container, fill="both", expand=True)
            self.runbox.lift()

class Trace32(tk.Frame):
    pass

class TMEConfig(tk.Frame):
    pass

root = tk.Tk()
params = RunParameters()

nb = ttk.Notebook(root)
nb.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

runbox = Runbox(nb, params)

test_info = TestInfo(nb, runbox = runbox)
test_list = TestList(nb, runbox = runbox)
trace32 = Trace32(nb)
tme_config = TMEConfig(nb)

nb.add(test_info, text="Test Info")
nb.add(test_list, text="Test List")
nb.add(trace32, text="Trace32")
nb.add(tme_config, text="TME config")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what @jasonharper suggested 6 hours ago. Unfortunately he didn't put his comment as answer. I will accept yours, but have a question: is same trick available for `grid` layout?

Comment: @Noob: yes, `grid`, `pack`, and `place` all support the `in_` parameter.